# Flash player on Scientific Linux 6.5

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux, adobe-flash

After a:

```
yum install -y flash-plugin
```

and a

```
USERNAME="USERNAMEHERE"; mkdir -p "/home/$USERNAME/.firefox/plugins"; ln -s "/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so" "/home/$USERNAME/.firefox/plugins"
```

I could always install flash player for Scientific Linux. But now, after a fresh install of Scientific Linux 6.5.. I do the same, but in the about:plugins there isn't any...

**My queston**: Why? What am I missing?

UPDATE: yes, the Firefox is 64 bit too: it's from:

```
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/en-US/
```

Comment: Is version of firefox also 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it out in the weekend, the main solution was to put the libflashplayer.so to the good directory.. and the directory was: "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins" ... so not the firefox/plubins..

a little bit further on installing Firefox correctly:

```
# I used it after: 
yum --releasever=6.5 update
# use BleachBit regularly!

#############################################
# 1) cd to home dir
cd

#############################################
# 2) download firefox
lynx -dump https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/en-US/ | awk '/.tar.bz2/ && /https/ {print $2}' | xargs -I {} wget {} -O firefox.tar.bz2

#############################################
# 3) extract it, if there was an old one, rename it..
mv .firefox .firefox-OLD-`date +%F`; mv .mozilla .mozilla-OLD-`date +%F`; tar -xjf firefox.tar.bz2; mv "firefox" ".firefox"; rm firefox.tar.bz2

#############################################
# 4) install rpmforge to get flash in the repositories + install flash
# ONLY THESE LINES NEEDED TO BE RUN BY ROOT
yum install -y rpmforge-release; ln -s "/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so" "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins"

#############################################
# 5) configure firefox (BY HAND)
# main: home page, download place
# tabs: no warnings
# applications: always ask ALL
# privacy: don't track, don't remember history, delete all history, don't suggest anything
# advanced: NO auto/smooth scrolling, NO spell checking, DON'T check if browser is default, DON'T let any statistics to send, etc. certificates: tick in OCSP as mandatory

# Add-ons
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wot-safe-browsing-tool
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus
https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-ssl-243978

extras: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-whitelist-with-buttons
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/requestpolicy

#############################################
# 6) 
about:config

app.update.silent
true

network.dns.disableIPv6
true

browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone
false

browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo
1

browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo
1

geo.enabled
false

network.http.sendRefererHeader
0

pdfjs.disabled
true

noscript.showPermanent
false

plugin.state.flash
1

# useragent: 
New -> String
general.useragent.override
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0

#############################################
7) disable flash cookies. Go to
https://www.youtube.com/
right click a flash element
Right click -> Global Settings... -> Storage TAB -> Block all sites from storing information on this computer
Camera and Mic TAB -> Block all sites from using the camera and microphone
Playback -> Block all sites from using peer-assisted networking

#############################################
```

Comment: do **NOT install** the so called "Web of Trust" (**WOT**), it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html